# Multiple commands on a single line in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

In Unix, we can put multiple commands in a single line like this:

```
$ date ; ls -l ; date
```

I tried a similar thing in Windows:

```
 > echo %TIME% ; dir ; echo %TIME
```

But it printed the time and doesn't execute the command `dir`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Use:

```
echo %time% & dir & echo %time%
```

This is, from memory, equivalent to the semi-colon separator in `bash` and other UNIXy shells.

There's also `&&` (or `||`) which only executes the second command if the first succeeded (or failed),  but the single ampersand `&` is what you're looking for here.

---

That's likely to give you the same time however since environment variables tend to be evaluated on read rather than execute.

You can get round this by turning on delayed expansion:

```
pax> cmd /v:on /c "echo !time! & ping 127.0.0.1 >nul: & echo !time!"
15:23:36.77
15:23:39.85
```

That's needed from the command line. If you're doing this inside a script, you can just use `setlocal`:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
echo !time! & ping 127.0.0.1 >nul: & echo !time!
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Issue is it works partially. the first and last %time% prints the same time even when the command (in middle) takes atleast 40 seconds to complete.( I run my script instead of dir command)

Comment: That's because the environment variables are evaluated when the command is _read_ rather than executed. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Still the issue persists. The script is exiting with code 1. But still the second echo prints the same time  See this op      12:57:56.93
A thread exited while 3 threads were running.
12:57:56.93

Comment: I tended to use `time /t` (or `echo.|time`) instead of `echo %time%` to circumvent the issue.

Comment: @Joey, that will work since it's not an environment variable. But you should be using `!time! rather than `%time%` - the former is the one with deferred behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but then I need a new `cmd` with `/v:on`. I'm lazy :P (and I have long used [`timethis`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3087) for this anyway)

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo and joey . I used both of your ideas and able to get the time taken

Comment: Also before i saw your answer i wrote a small batch file like this echo %time% %* echo %time and passed the script which i need to execute with arguments as an argument to this batch script and achieved the required output

Comment: Any idea how to get %errorlevel% to be correct on following calls?

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved also with [scriptrunner](https://ss64.com/nt/scriptrunner.html)

```
ScriptRunner.exe -appvscript demoA.cmd arg1 arg2 -appvscriptrunnerparameters -wait -timeout=30 -rollbackonerror -appvscript demoB.ps1 arg3 arg4 -appvscriptrunnerparameters -wait -timeout=30
```

Which also have some features as rollback , timeout and waiting.