# Condensing Batch File to a Single Line

Tags: batch-file

I'm programatically creating a batch file. Limitations in the language I'm using (old delphi) mean I can't write to separate lines to the .bat. So my batch has to be a single line.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922224/multiple-commands-on-a-single-line-in-a-windows-batch-file) and was able to condense a few of the lines. But using the double ampersands `&&` doesn't work for some of the lines and I haven't had success with the ping pause either.

Here's where I am at...

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions&&set myfolder_=Z:\MyFolder
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o:d /a:-d /b "%myfolder_%\*.mp3"') do (set latest_=%myfolder_%\%%~nxf)
if defined latest_ (echo rem latest file "%latest_%"&xcopy "%latest_%" "Z:\MyFolder\PlayMe" /V /D /Y) else (echo No designated files found in "%myfolder_%")   
Pause
```

Is it possible to further reduce the lines of code to a single line so that the batch still runs?

Comment: at first, you should use one ampersand, not two. Two ampersands work like `if %errorlevel%==0`

Comment: Thanks I have updated the example. However moving lines 2 & 3 with a single `&` still breaks the script.

Comment: try to put them in brackets...

Comment: I put line 2 in brackets, preceded it with `&` and moved it to line 1 and got the same result. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I believe what was intended was `line1&(line2)&(line3)` However, this scheme is doomed to fail because you are using `%var%` which would be replaced at parse-time by (probably) an empty string. At a guess, I'd suggest you need to include `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in your `setlocal` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%`

Comment: ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and !var! got it. Thanks. I'll mark it s answered if you submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in your setlocal and use !var! in place of %var%