# VS/C++ commands not executed in Msbuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following configuration in my VS/C++ project(.vcxproj):

```
<PreBuildEvent>
  <Command>mkdir Hello</Command>
  <Command>mkdir World</Command>
  <Message>Gratz</Message>
</PreBuildEvent>
```

The problem is that only `World` directory is created and the message in NOT displayed in the output console.

Comment: Are you sure you can put two commands in the same event? Sounds to me like you're breaking the mechanism when it encounters a second command, and a cursory search of the documentation reveals no examples with two or more commands per event.

Comment: Can you send me the link to the documentation?

Comment: Can you simply Google it yourself? Wait, does that mean you're programming without already having found the documentation? lol no wonder you're having problems!! :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit YES, i simply dont know how to google. 
I just wanted to know which documentation you were referring to. 
I suggest you dont comment if you dont know the answer or if you can't add any valuable information.

Comment: Glad I tried to help you. It has been a delightful experience interacting with you. See ya

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope not.

Comment: first paragraph: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx - no idea why the message isn't shown (are you *sure* it isn't, I cannot reproduce it). Also, what is your actual *question* here. You only lay out some problem.

Comment: @stijn How can I create "Hello" and "world" directories and message "Gratz" when it's done in "PreBuildEvent". and im positive that message ist shown, but it may cause by visual studio setting.

Comment: :P you should really learn how to google/ddg/bing, it will make your programmer life much easier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922224/multiple-commands-on-a-single-line-in-a-windows-batch-file, so `mkdir Hello & mkdir World`?