# Batch command no longer working when split by & character

Tags: windows, cmd

I wrote a batch script to get a yes or no from the user. And it works. But when I put all into one line with & between the commands, it no longer works.

Here is the working script:

```
@echo off
set /p Input=continue?
if "%Input%"=="n" exit
@echo continue
PAUSE
```

and here is the not working script:

```
@echo off & set /p Input=continue? & if "%Input%"=="n" exit & @echo continue & PAUSE
```

This one doesn't work, either.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & @echo off & set /p Input=continue? & if "!Input!"=="n" exit & @echo continue
```

Nor this one:

```
@echo off & set /p Input=continue?
if "!Input!"=="n" exit & @echo continue
```

I have an update: If I make a new line, the second script works. But it's not where one might expect.

```
@echo off & set /p Input=continue? & if "%Input%"=="n" exit
@echo continue & PAUSE
```

Comment: What do you think `&` means in such a script?

Comment: I think it works like a semicolon. I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922224/multiple-commands-on-a-single-line-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: You need another layer of expansion because `%Input%` is expanded at the beginning of the line read, not after the `set /p` input. _You should also perform some verification of the input, before proceeding, because the end user could enter anything at all, including problematic characters._

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: @Compo how would I go about adding another layer of expansion? In terms of verification, are you talking like an injection?

Comment: You could start by taking a look at the related link in the comment above.

Comment: @Compo the link tells me that I need my variable reference in a different block than my variable assignment. Or I need delayed expansion. Neither of these worked.

Comment: yes, it works. But you don't see the effect, because `exit` closes the separate process (started by `cmd /v:on /c`) and not your main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to run this in one line is to prevent delayed expansion altogether, by using the more robust `choice` command:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Continue"&(If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B)&Pause
```

*Obviously the rest of your code would continue on that or the next line.*

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that the if statement needed to be in parentheses? What is the /B for?

Comment: @Salmon, you could remove the parentheses to find out! _They effectively isolate the `Exit` command from the `Pause` command_. To find out how the `Exit` command works, open a Command Prompt window and enter `exit /?`. Put simply `Exit` on its own will exit `cmd.exe`, _(close the window)_, whereas the `/B` option will only exit the script. If you were to run your batch file from the Command Prompt, as opposed to say, a double-click, you are unlikely to want the window to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

When you insist on doing it in one line (I see no need for that - hey, it's a batch file - keep it readable), use an alternative:

```
@echo off & choice /m "Continue?" & if errorlevel 2 (exit) else (echo continue & pause)
```

Comment: Each line is actually a string in a string array in a java program, and the script gets run with ProcessBuilder. And for some reason, it only works when it's one line.

Comment: Why is it that `echo continue & pause` need to be on a new line?

Comment: because that's how it was in your question at the time of this answer. Changed it to the new requirement.

Comment: when you need a command-line solution, please tag your question as `cmd`. The `batch-file` tag claims you need a batch file (where pressing several commands into one line is generally counter-productive)