# Pause command not working in .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file

The batch file has only two lines:

```
c:\program.exe ...
pause
```

but pause does't run after "program" completes... I don't see that "press any key message" :(

If I move pause on the first line, then it magically works.

Comment: I would say the pause is never running. does the window remain open if you take the pause out completely? perhaps the program is not exiting. you can try running the batch file via the command prompt as well so you can see what the output is when its finished.

Comment: Can you provide some more info?  Is `program.exe` maybe a Windows command that doesn't terminate?

Comment: Use ```start /WAIT``` to launch ```program.exe```.

Comment: it's [phpunit](https://svn.typo3.org/Teams/forge.typo3.org/hudson-helpers/tools/PHPUnit/PHPUnit-3.5/phpunit.bat). it terminates bc i can see when it finishes..

Comment: c:\program.exe is not a batch file.... ;-)

Comment: yes, sorry i didn't think it would matter..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It fails because you are not running an executable directly - you are running it via the phpunit.bat batch file (based on information in comment added to question).

You must CALL a batch file from within another batch file if you want to return to the caller

```
call phpunit
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Try saving before opening the bat file, it worked for me