# Delete all files that have same name as a .jpg recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a small batch script for my "*Send to*" menu that deletes certain files:

I have a lot of files named in this convention: `foo.xxx, foo.jpg, bar.xxx and bar.jpg`. I want to delete `.xxx` files where there is a corresponding `.jpg` file recursively for all nested folders below the level from where I call this script.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files) I came up with the following:

```
@ echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do echo "%%f"
```

This at least lists the `.jpg` files it seems but I get an error message that reads like this:

> "UNC-Pfade werden nicht unterstützt. Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt."

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139719/delete-all-files-of-specific-type-extension-recursively-down-a-directory-using) which shows how to delete files recursively but I do not really understand how to combine the two solutions to delete only those `.xxx` files for which I found a `.jpg`. Furthermore it would be nice if there where some sanity check that checks if there really is a `.xxx` file with the current name, sometimes there are `.jpg` files in these folders that have no corresponding `.xxx` file.

It seems I can remove by [file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension) like this:

```
@ echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do echo "%%~nf"
```

But now I have no complete path to delete the wanted files? Is this correct so far? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a network drive?

Comment: Yes, it sould work on a networkdrive ( where the data is stored) but also locally ond my drives.

Comment: I don't speak German very well, but this "UNC Pfade" wording means you can't do this on network path. Try to map this network path to a letter (with SUBST command), and then work on usual DOS path.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the script even lists the correct path and files as is.... BUt i stll do not understand how to delete those files that i want. I could solve the UNC-PAth error later.

Comment: Given that the command extensions are enabled, which is the default configuration anyway, `pushd` does support UNC paths and maps such ti a temporary drive letter, which becomes the current working directory (`popd` deletes the temporary drive letter then). Is this the whole script you have troubles with, or is there any more code you did not share so far?

Comment: There can be many (like 20 to 50) but not more. xxx stands as a placeholder as this is data from a  REM/EDX mashine which stores the data with a different extenison based on what has been meassured. 

Would i have to add popd "%~1" at the end of the script?

But i am mainyl interested in how to delete the files.

Comment: You could set the "read only" attribute on all `*.jpg`, then `for /R %%a in (*.jpg) do del "%%~dpn.*` (it will not delete Read-Only files), then remove the read only attributes again. [attrib](https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html)

Comment: So :`@ echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do del "%%~dpnf.xxx"

popd` seems to work... I hope that there is nothing dangerous about this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: for ".xxx" yes, it works. For "all but .jpg" it doesn't. For testing, you can disable the delete with `... do ECHO del "%%~dpnf.xxx"`, so you can verify it does what you want before removing the `ECHO` command to enable the `del` command. (Best practice: work on a copy or your data or have a backup)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
@ echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /R %%I in (*.jpg) do del "%%~dpnI.vgd"

popd
```

See comments for all contributions.

Comment: `... do del "%%~dpnI.vgd" 2>nul` to suppress the error message, when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Batch script for my "Send to" menu: pushd "%~1" will not work. There can be 50 .xxx You have to write part of your command 50 times. What is the path to the root UNC folder?