# Recursively delete certain file type from specific folder

Tags: batch-file

On windows 10 I have a folder with numerous sub directories.
In some of those sub directories is a folder named "source".
I am trying to make a bat file to search for all the "source" folders and delete only the .png files from inside the "source" folders only.

I thought this should work but it doesnt

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s "source"') do del "%%F\*.png"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: I recommend this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139719/delete-all-files-of-specific-type-extension-recursively-down-a-directory-using

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. As we both thought, my batch should have worked.
Turns out after a reboot it does haha.