# R: send multiple commands to Windows' cmd

Tags: r, cmd

I think and hope this is super easy, but I am jsut too stupid/blind:

I want to use `system` and not only open the command-line of windows, but to perform a simple copy task within it:

```
system('cmd' , 'copy Frame_Ind* all.dat')
```

So I thought... I want to copy alle files which start with "Frame_Ind" together into one that is calles "all.dat".

Can you tell me how to prompt more than one command with `system`?

I know this is a weird workaround, but it would help me a lot! Thanks and Cheers,
Al

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want but to run multiple commands on the the cmd line from R you could: write a .bat file and tell that to run from within R, make multiple system() calls or use the syntax from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd in one call to system()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
shell('copy Frame_Ind* all.dat')
```

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I searched for! Thanks