# Sublime Text launch separate command window (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, windows, sublimetext2, build-system

I am trying to do all the programs in [*Programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321776410) as an exercise and to familiarize myself with some of the finer details (I didn't go to school for computer science) of C (on a *Windows 8* machine).

A lot of the book is simple programs and I'd like to enter the programs with [*Sublime Text*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) (as opposed to *Code::Blocks*, which I have been using with [*openFrameworks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFrameworks)). Is there an easy way to launch a separate command window for a program after it is compiled.

It's kind of hacky, but I changed the "run" version of build to launch the compiled program

```
"cmd": ["${file_base_name}.exe"]
```

but apparently, the Sublime Text documentation says that [GUI's are suppressed](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).

What I want to do is launch a separate command prompt window. The primary reason is that `scanf` does not halt for input. Let me know if there is a quick workaround:

- some workaround in Sublime Text ( a setting I'm not aware of)
- how to change the build file to launch an actual window
- some way to easily launch a separate window in C

Answer (score 4):

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/c $file_base_name.exe"],
    "selector": "text.c",
    "shell": "true"
}
```

The cmd `start` command opens a new window of the command passed to it.
Note that to keep the window from closing immediately at the end of your programs, you'll have end them with `system("pause");` or `getch();`, or replace /c with /k to keep cmd up.

**EDIT:** after more [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/2757644) and debugging:

```
"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name.exe & pause"]
```

I had the same issue with Java, trying to create a Run Variant, and eventually came out with this:

```
"variants":
[
    {
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/c", "java $file_base_name & pause"],
        "name": "Run"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/guilherme-p/Sublime-Build-Systems/blob/master/myC.sublime-build

```
{
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k gcc $file_base_name.c -o $file_base_name.exe && $file_base_name.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true
}
```