# Sublime Text 2 Run built file after building

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

So I'm new to this but I am using Sublime Text 2 on Mac OS X and the problem is that when i simply run my c++ code it runs in a local output tab and it dont allow me to do any input, so to input variables i need to build my code and then locate it in finder and open in terminal, but is there a way to allow input in that little output windows or simply tell ST2 to open the  built file just after building it?

P.S.
I found the answear to my own question :D 
I will add it so if someone needs it - it will be here.
so you need to eddit c++.sublime-build file - just add this

```
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && open -a Terminal.app '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
```

before

```
 "variants":
```

and the when you build your programm it will just open it in terminal

Comment: If you're using Windows, this link answer the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554858/sublime-text-launch-separate-command-window-c-c/18680590#18680590