# How can I run multiple commands at once from windows command line using c++ / c?

Tags: c++, c, cmd

how can I run multiple commands at once from windows command line?
i want to set a couple of env variables and use them in the c++ program.
Like:

```
set VAR=Hello and set VAR2=BYE
```

and same program should do:

```
echo %VAR% and echo %VAR2%
```

and the output should be:

> Hello BYE

How to achieve this in c/c++ ? any way to do this using system() function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: Aren't you actually asking about passing parameters to an application through command line?

Comment: us2012: ya similar to that. Thanks :)
Dariusz not parameters but two separate commands using same shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may execute a number of shell commands with the `&` seperator:

`echo %VAR% & echo %VAR2%`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430/1504523) SO answer to get more details.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately this will put the output seperated in two lines.

`Hello`

`BYE`

However, there is a solution for that too:

`SET /P Var=%VAR%<NUL & echo %VAR2%`

will output

`Hello BYE`

**Edit 2:**

Do not use `system()`, better use the [CreateProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows
you to set creation flags like `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Comment: cool ! thanks !
and do you know how to avoid command prompt from popping up while using system() ?

Comment: I've added information on how to resolve the newline issue, See my edit.

Comment: but still the command prompt window pops up na? how to avoid it? i want the output to be read just by my program, console should not appear . anyway to do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot !
#ifdef _Win32
    //Windows OS, use CreateProcess
#else
    //Not windows
This is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `&` separator:

```
set VAR=Hello & set VAR2=BYE
```