# How to Run Input Cmd Commands By VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have a problem with CMD in a VB.NET project I'm making. How can I input three different commands to the same CMD window I open through a Button on my Form. Whenever I click the button on my form I want the CMD window to open, execute the first command and then automatically proceed to execute the next command and so on.

The three commands must be run in the same sequence in order to do its job.

The code I used:

```
Process.start ("cmd","/k First Code "  & "Second Code " & "Third Code")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write out a batch file to disk and then run the batch file.

Also see:  [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

It looks like you can use & to separate commands.

I'd do something like:

```
Process.Start(String.Format("cmd /k {0} & {1} & {2}", "First Code", "Second Code", "Third Code"))
```

This might work better: (as an example)

```
Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k {0} & {1} & {2}", "dir c:", "dir /w c:", "pause"))
```

You can substitute your own commands in here.

Comment: I Tryd ro Make a Batch file but when i run it ,,the First Command procced but the otjer commands i write doesn't procced

Comment: I updated my answer with how I would do it using String.Format

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't work it just open the Cmd and do nothing ⁉⁉⁉

Comment: I put a second example where I separated out the "cmd" from the command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using, thanks to the other answer

```
Process.start ( "cmd" , "/k First code second code -c Third Code " )
```