# Execute two commands on cmd

Tags: c#, batch-file

I write test console program. This program execute cmd with two line command. But how it's do?
Instead of this large code, how write more easy code?

```
String command = @"cd c:\\test";//command get to current folder 
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
String command = @"echo 'Hello world' > test.txt";//command write Hello world to text file
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: no two commands necessaray here: `> c:\test\test.txt" echo Hello World`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `&` operator.

For example:

```
dir & echo foo
```

For yours:

```
cd c:\\test & echo 'Hello world' > test.txt
```

Also see: [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

you can put you command in a batch file `yourcmd.bat`, in your case the `yourcmd.bat` will like this:

```
cd c:\test
echo "Hello world" > test.txt
```

or

```
cd c:\test & echo "Hello world" > test.txt
```

then you can just call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourcmd.bat");` method, this works.