# Activating a Python virtual environment & changing directory in one shortcut (with cmd)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do the following:

Open a CMD prompt

Activate a virtual environment

Change the current directory to my project folder

In essence, I need to execute the following commands sequentially:

```
C:\Envs\djangorocks\Scripts\activate
cd "D:\GitHub\steelrumors"
```

I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd), but creating a shortcut as follows gives me nothing (just a plain CMD prompt in the currently active directory):

```
cmd \k "C:\Envs\djangorocks\Scripts\activate" & "cd "D:\GitHub\steelrumors""
```

After quite a while of searching I'm still doing it manually, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"creating a shortcut as follows gives me nothing (just a plain CMD prompt in the currently active directory):"

```
cmd \k "C:\Envs\djangorocks\Scripts\activate" & "cd "D:\GitHub\steelrumors""
```

Observations:

- `cmd \k` should be `cmd /k`.
- `&` should be `&&` when using a shortcut.
- You dont need all the `"` characters.

Try the following as the shortcut target:

```
cmd /k C:\Envs\djangorocks\Scripts\activate && cd D:\GitHub\steelrumors
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating a batch file (e.g. c:\scripts\launchEnv.cmd) that does something like the following:

```
@echo off
C:\Envs\djangorocks\Scripts\activate
cd /d "D:\GitHub\steelrumors"
```

Then create a shortcut that invokes `cmd /k c:\scripts\launchEnv.cmd` .

Some notes:

- the `@echo off` will prevent the commands from showing up in the cmd windows. If you do want to see the commands, then omit that line from your batch file
- you'll need the `/d` param when changing directories to make sure you actually change and navigate there, independent of where the script is currently executing from.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the great answer from @DavidPostill I've added an additional step to run a command from the newly created python env.

In my example below, I'm launching a new instance of the awesome data mining program, *orange*, from an anaconda env called `orange`. I've also cd'ed to the directory containing my orange data files. Note that I had to use the quotation marks "" to make it work.

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "F: && cd \Dropbox\IT\Python\Orange && C:\Users\dreme\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat orange && python -m Orange.canvas"`