# Running node-inspector and node-debug with npm run

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, node-debugger

How to run two script at once with `npm run`?
First of all I know grunt or gulp but I want to make it without another js modules. 
To make this I have this script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./node/www",
  "nodemon": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon node/www.js -i './e2e-tests/**' -i './node_modules/**' -i '.idea/**' -i './node/log/**' -w './node/server/**/*' -V -L",
  "nodeInspector": "./node_modules/.bin/node-inspector --save-live-edit=true",
  "debug": "node-debug ./node/www.js",
  "ins": "npm run nodeInspector & npm run debug"
}
```

I want to run with `npm run ins` but it only fires node-inspector.
[image]

Comment: Try to change & to &&

Comment: I think you need to read this question, because it's windows specific question. Also try ; instead of & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run both commands. They each need their own console

Comment: For windows I can't do it but I saw some screenshot from linux. I changed to use grunt.

Answer (score 0):

If `node-debug` comes from `node-inspector` package, then you don't need to start a new `node-inspector` instance, `node-debug` will start it automatically for you.

This is what node-debug performs under the hood ([source code](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/blob/4874d017f8f71a236073f8c4c2202895a0e0a2c7/bin/node-debug.js#L28-L30)):

1. Run node-inspector.
2. Run the supplied script in debug mode
3. Open the user's browser, pointing it at the inspector.

In fact, running both `node-inspector` and `node-debug` will not work as intended, as the second `node-inspector` instance won't be able to attach to the same port where the first instance already listens.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it happen on one line that's why I changed to grunt with concurrent:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concurrent: {
            options: {
                limit: 3,
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            },
            debug: {
                tasks: ['node-inspector', 'nodemon:debug'],
                options: {
                    logConcurrentOutput: true
                }
            }
        },
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: "node/www.js",
                options: {
                    ignore: ['node/public/**'],
                    callback: function (nodemon) {
                        nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
                        });

                        // opens browser on initial server start
                        nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
                            console.log("nodemon config:update oldu");
                            // Delay before server listens on port
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                require('open')('http://localhost:3000');
                            }, 1000);
                        });

                        // refreshes browser when server reboots
                        nodemon.on('restart', function () {
                            // Delay before server listens on port
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                //require('fs').writeFileSync('.rebooted', 'rebooted');
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            debug: {
                script: './node/www.js',
                options: {
                    ignore: ['node/log/*.log','node/public/**','node/views/**','doc/**','e2e-tests/**','.idea'],
                    callback: function (nodemon) {
                        nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
                            console.log("Nodemon debug callback fonksiyonu nodemon.onLog olayı");
                        });

                        // opens browser on initial server start
                        nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
                            console.log("Nodemon debug callback fonksiyonu nodemon.onConfig:Update olayı");
                            // Delay before server listens on port
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                require('open')('http://localhost:3000');
                                require('open')('http://localhost:1337/debug?port=5858');
                            }, 1000);
                        });

                        // refreshes browser when server reboots
                        nodemon.on('restart', function () {
                            console.log("Nodemon debug callback fonksiyonu nodemon.onRestart olayı");
                            // Delay before server listens on port
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                //require('fs').writeFileSync('.rebooted', 'rebooted');
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    },
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                    watch: ['Gruntfile.js', 'node/server', 'package.json']
                }
            }
        },
        'node-inspector': {
            custom: {
                options: {
                    'web-port': 1337,
                    'web-host': 'localhost',
                    'debug-port': 5857,
                    'save-live-edit': true,
                    'no-preload': true,
                    'stack-trace-limit': 4,
                    'hidden': ['node_modules']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // Çalışması test edildi ve iki pencerede hem test hem uygulama açıyor.
    grunt.registerTask('nodemon-debug', ['concurrent:debug']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run node-inspector and nodemon from a script using concurently

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

"dev": "npm install && concurrently \"node-inspector --web-port 9090\" \"nodemon --debug .\""