# "call-system-showing-output" in LispWorks

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, common-lisp, lispworks

I want to call a Java class in Lisp with this command :

```
(sys:call-system-showing-output
    "cd C:/Users/iliass/Downloads/SBC-Projet/stanford-postagger
java -mx300m -classpath stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger -textFile tag_input.txt > tag_output.txt"
    :prefix "&&&")`
```

When I run the command `cd ....` from the command shell `cmd.exe` it works and the file `tag_output.txt` is generated, but when I call it from Lisp it doesn't work.

I'm using LispWorks on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that putting a newline into your command will split it into two commands.  According to the documentation, it should work with a semicolon, though.

Comment: For Unix shells. For Windows see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd