# Multi-line build events result into locking problems

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, post-build-event, build-events

I have a Visual Studio solution with x projects. Each project has (post) build events consisting of two or more lines.

When the build events are executed, a locking problem occurs:

```
The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'D:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpff905f7a0bf94226b86296693df6861c.exec.cmd' because it is being used by another process.
```

I suspect that Visual Studio writes the multiple lines to the unique temporary file which should be executed by cmd.exe. I first suspected there was a conflict between parallel builds, but since each build seems to create a unique file, that cannot be the cause.

Anohter nice detail is that the file in question, is not deleted after the error. When I open it, it is empty.

So...

- Why is there a conflict?
- Why is it empty?

Comment: Have you tried using MSBuild diagnostics from the Tools/Options menu?

Comment: I have the same problem. However, we got exactly 1 project with exactly 2 lines of post-build steps. Plus it is also affecting VS 2015 ... You could try to concatenate them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd - however, mine was not fixed by this trick

Comment: At this moment we blame the virus scanner (McAfee).

Comment: Changing the TMP environment variable worked for me, see answers [elsewhere][1]  


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053112/msbuild-error-the-specified-task-executable-cmd-exe-could-not-be-run-the-proce