# batch: Execute two commands in sequence

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a little batch script, and i'm trying to execute two different commands in a new command window.

Now, the window opens, but i'm unable to execute the commands in sequence.

Here's the code:

```
:KARMA_TEST_START
ECHO.
start cmd /k gulp compileUnit && karma start
GOTO MENU
```

I've tried everithing mentioned here: [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd) but with no luck.

I'd like the new window to open, execute `gulp compileUnit`, after that, execute karma start and stay open (cause karma start should listen to changes and re-run every time by itself, that's why i need it to stay open).

Any help? thanks

Comment: Try: `start cmd /k gulp compileUnit ^& karma start`. As you have it, the two commands are the `start` command and `karma` one. This way, both commands are passed as  parameters of `start`. If you want to insert _two_ ampersand characters (for conditional execution), use `^&^&`

Comment: awesome! it works. Thank you very much for your help and explanation

Comment: @Aacini please turn this into an answer so that we can get rid of this seemingly unanswered question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `start cmd /k gulp compileUnit ^& karma start`. As you have it, the two commands are the `start` command and `karma` one. This way, both commands are passed as parameters of `start`. If you want to insert *two* ampersand characters (for conditional execution), use `^&^&`.