# How to execute two cmd commands in the same instance of cmd using python

Tags: python, cmd

Whenever I try to do

```
os.system("net view /all")
```

with python, the code gets executed, but it instantly closes, so I can't read the output. I looked around a bit, and found that you can use

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```

to do something like

```
time.sleep()
```

in python, but if I do

```
os.system("net view /all")
os.system("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul")
```

They are executed in different instances of cmd, one after the other, so the problem remains. How would I make them be run in the same instance, or how would I be able to put a delay after

`net view /all`

so that I can read the output? (Only solutions using stock python libs please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them together:

```
os.system("net view /all & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul")
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me, with a "&" instead of the ";"

Answer (score 0):

I think your question boils down to what shell is getting called when you call os.system() and how *it* would let you run two commands in sequence. If you're using `bash`, this would look like

```
os.system("net view /all; sleep 5")
```

for, e.g., a 5 second wait after the command executed.

Under Windows, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd?rq=1) answer appears to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add a "&" between the two commands, so now it looks like

```
os.system("net view /all & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul")
```