# How to carry out more than one command in a single line

Tags: windows

I want to execute a command on cmd windows

```
cd document
ren log.txt 1.txt
```

But I want to execute the command in a single line

example :
cd document / ren log.txt 1.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only run the second command if the first command succeeds:

```
cd document && ren log.txt 1.txt
```

To run the two commands separately use

```
cd document & ren log.txt 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look and [Microsoft's Command Shell Overview](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true), specifically see the section regarding Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols

> **Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols**
>
> You can run multiple commands from a single command line or script using conditional processing symbols. When you run multiple commands with conditional processing symbols, the commands to the right of the conditional processing symbol act based upon the results of the command to the left of the conditional processing symbol. For example, you might want to run a command only if the previous command fails. Or, you might want to run a command only if the previous command is successful.
>
> You can use the special characters listed in the following table to pass multiple commands.
>
> `command1 & command2`
>
> Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.
>
> `command1 && command2`
>
> Use to run the command following && only if the command preceding the symbol is successful. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command completed successfully.
>
> `command1 || command2`
>
> Use to run the command following || only if the command preceding || fails. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command did not complete successfully (receives an error code greater than zero).
>
> `(command1 & command2)`
>
> Use to group or nest multiple commands.
>
> `command1 parameter1;parameter2`
>
> or
>
> `command1 parameter1,parameter2`
>
> Use to separate command parameters.