# command line execute .exe from it's own folder

Tags: command-line, directory, executable

My .exe relies on configuration and other files in it's folder.
So I'd like to start it from it's folder, but with a single line.

So instead of:

```
D:\APPS\Program.exe
```

something like:

```
cd D:\APPS\ Program.exe
```

So the root folder is `D:\APPS\` instead of `D:`

I could make a bat file with these as separate lines.
But that's a lot of extra work.

Is there a way to execute this in a single line?

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Comment: Thanks, that works. Use & to separate two commands in one line.