# Why does 'msg * alarm' disappear after a while?

Tags: windows, parameters, native, executable, default-parameters

I have a small powershell script which allows me to quickly set an alarm for myself. It basically just waits a specified number of minutes and then calls

> msg * alarm!

This works well - a message box pops up. The only problem is it disappears after a while - so if I'm not at my desk, I'll miss the message box.

According to the documentation, [found here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490796.aspx), this is the behaviour when I don't specify a time value.

> /time: seconds   : Specifies the amount of time the message you sent is displayed on the user's screen. Once the time limit is reached, the message disappears. If no time limit is set, the message remains on the user's screen until the user sees the message and clicks OK.

However this isn't the case and it does disappear. Right now, I have to specify an arbitarily high number for it to stay.

```
    msg * /time:999999 alarm!
```

Comment: ok can someone explain this why this is a bad question?

Comment: It is not a programming/development question. It is a question about the behavior of a Windows system utility.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - really? questions regarding command line commands are out of scope for this site now? There's literally a tag for this and this question has like 300+ upvotes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: I didn't downvote; it was just a guess on my part.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with the timer in the script...

Comment: @andlabs - Whatever shell you use to start msg will result in the same behavior. This is definitely not powershell related, just msg.exe related. The winapi tag is debatable though. Perhaps a Windows Internals tag is needed.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers oh, `msg` is not a PowerShell command? Good to know; thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tracing the call's with `cdb` shows following function of interest when starting `msg.exe` and passing it the maximum timeout value of `999999`:

`command: msg * /time:999999 alarm`

The timeout value of `f423f` *`(999999)`* gets passed to `ShowMessageBox` through the `rax` register.

```
WINSTA!WinStationSendMessageW+0x353:
000007fe`fbf1ec93 e874deffff      
call    WINSTA!CSmartSession::ShowMessageBox (000007fe`fbf1cb0c)
rax=00000000000f423f rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000010
```

---

Starting `msg.exe` without any timeout value shows `3c` *`(60)`* being passed to the `ShowMessageBox` function.

`command: msg * alarm`

```
WINSTA!WinStationSendMessageW+0x353:
000007fe`fbf1ec93 e874deffff      
call    WINSTA!CSmartSession::ShowMessageBox (000007fe`fbf1cb0c)
rax=000000000000003c rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000010
```

---

My guess is that the documentation is not up-to-date *(if it ever was)*

Comment: Hi Lieven - just wondering, what is this cdb command that you're using to trace?

Comment: I used this one `cdb -c ".while (1) {tc;r}" msg.exe * /time:999999 alarm >> msgtrace.txt` and it did the job but I'm sure it can be optimized in many ways. The while loop should not be necessary for instance, I had to kill the debugger at the end because of the while loop, ...

Answer (score 1):

try`/time:0`, works for me, but waited for several minutes only