# Is there any way to display all the functions called by an executable in WinDBG (not just call stack)?

Tags: c, windows, windbg

I am trying to debug an executable that does not work properly (does not receive segmentation fault, it just doesn't do what he should do) using WinDbg. I would like to see a call stack with all the functions that are called while running the executable. Is this possible in WinDbg or any other debugger?

Comment: what is *all the functions that are called* ?

Comment: all the functions that the program goes through

Comment: what is function on binary level ? in exe only ?  windbg not do this. and even if some tool do - what this give you ? if you know some function which you think have problem - set bp here

Comment: is an executable (.exe) that calls a function in a library and this function calls other functions in the library (exported functions). I want to know if windbg can find out what functions are then called by the called function in the executable.

Comment: no. and this is useless info anyway. exist thousand functions and so what ? how many time called every function, with which parameters ? in which order ? return values, etc .

Comment: You can take a look at `wt` to start tracing your calls. Note that you'll only get function names when symbols can be resolved, otherwise you'll just get adresses. You can look at `tc` to dump a specific number of calls. It's not an entirly useless excercise. I have used it in the past to [trace a parameter passed to msg.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461255/52598)

Comment: Set a break point on return address and use wt or watch and trace it can give you a very detailed call flow summary

Comment: Even if RbMm may be right in the end, I guess there is a time when every developer wants to do this - and I think it's legitimate. Use `wt` as Lieven says. But - maybe do yourself a favor and try it with a simple app like calc.exe first. If you start doing this rigth from the initial breakpoint, you'll note it takes ~20 minutes to start up, instead of milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes as i commented use wt (watch and trace)
[Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/wt--trace-and-watch-data-)
it can be configured in several ways
like only first level calls
upto nth level calls only
only in specific modules
only in main module etc

below is a simple trace of a function in ntdll that crosses um-km boundary

```
0:000> u . l1
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11bf:
76ff6113 e870fffdff      call    ntdll!NtQueryInformationProcess (76fd6088)

0:000> bp .+5  //set a bp on return address
0:000> bl
 0 e 76ff6118     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11c4

0:000> wt
    2     0 [  0] ntdll!NtQueryInformationProcess
   27     0 [  0] aswhook
    1     0 [  1]   aswhook
   28     1 [  0] aswhook
    1     0 [  1]   0x6efc0480
    1     0 [  1]   0x6efc0485
    2     0 [  1]   ntdll!NtQueryInformationProcess
    2     0 [  2]     ntdll!KiFastSystemCall
    1     0 [  1]   ntdll!NtQueryInformationProcess
   46     8 [  0] aswhook
    3     0 [  1]   aswhook

Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=00000000 ebx=7ffdf000 ecx=e8cb8789 edx=ffffffff esi=ffffffff edi=00000000
eip=76ff6118 esp=0018f59c ebp=0018f6f4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11c4:
76ff6118 85c0            test    eax,eax
0:000>
```

Comment: The only WT I can find are (1) Windows Terminal and (2) a library. Where is it?

Comment: wt is a command in windbg  / cdb the official windows debugger by Microsoft the link in the answer is still correct click it to read the documents as answered