# Deleting file after progeam execution in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am having a simple question, having simple batch script:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do start /wait c:\some.exe -verbose c:\someLog.txt del c:\someLog.txt
```

after each execution file creates log, and I want to remove that log before next loop execution, execution works fine but when I add del command its having problems, it looks like log is being deleted to early.

Is there a possible way to delay del command ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running multiple command I usually nest them for readability.

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
    start /wait c:\some.exe -verbose c:\someLog.txt 
    del c:\someLog.txt 
)
```

You could probably do it this way as well

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (start /wait c:\some.exe -verbose c:\someLog.txt &del c:\someLog.txt)
```

But this does not mean that your executable is actually respecting the WAIT option.  Many programs do not.  I would just use the exe directly without using START at all.