# How to execute two commands in cmd (node and npm) and then start a browser when localhost is available

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

I got a task to create a powershell or a batch file on Windows which should, in sequence, start a "node file.js", then call a "npm start" command in another directory and then launch a browser to localhost:3000.
The problem is that I can not get the exact time when to launch the browser at the very end. I tried to concatenate commands with & and && ([How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)) but the browser got launched before the scripts reach the end in the first case, never in the second case. I guess cmd simply can't understand when node or npm commands are finished to be executed.

Does anybody have experience with this particular task?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Note that `&` is the unconditional command concatenation operator, whereas `&&` lets the second command execute only in case the first one succeeded, that is, its exit code was zero...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: DavidPostill, please note that one has his own life in addition to coding, so if I don't reply within 4 hours, I am not considering SO as a free script/code writing service.

Comment: This stated, I would be even happy to make this work as a cmd command: "node helloWorld.js && start http://localhost:8000". The first command opens a terminal window and the server is started. Then nothing happens. If I try to exit the terminal, then the browser opens but, obviously, can't reach the url I provided.