# Writing a Batch file for cmd

Tags: file, batch-file, curl, command

i must write a batch file which changes the directory and than I want to start a command in this directory. It is a curl command like "curl --help"

what I have now is =

```
start cmd /K "cd C:\Users\myname\mycurl"
```

its working fine. and now i want to runn this command from this directorty.

```
curl --help
```

Can somebody help me please

thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. The command you have reported as working fine is not correct, I would suggest that this should read, `START "" CMD /K "CD C:\Users\myname\mycurl"`. That said if there really was a need for `START` then using it's **`/D`** option may also help, `START "" /D "%UserProfile%\mycurl" CMD /K`; _(if you don't wish to open a new cmd window then add the **`/B`** option, `START "" /B /D "%UserProfile%\mycurl" CMD /K`)_. To directly run the command you have asked about you can add it to the end thus: `START "" /D "%UserProfile%\mycurl" CMD /K "curl --help"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. A simple approach would be:

   start cmd /K "cd C:\Users\myname\mycurl && curl --help"

Using command1 && command2: you can execute command2 only if command1 succeeds.

Also refer: [combining commands in DOS/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd/8055430#8055430)

2. You may also write a batch files with multiple commands. And invoke that batch file from the new command prompt.

Example:
bat1.bat

```
start cmd /K "bat2.bat"
```

bat2.bat

```
echo running bat2.bat
cd C:\Users\myname\mycurl
curl --help
```

Comment: it's better `start /D "path_to_start" cmd /K "curl..."`

Comment: thank you. I'm now using "&& Curl --help" and i want now to add a second curl command how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in having a batch starting another cmd with /K to stay open and then issue a command which fills more than a screen forcing to scroll back.

Either:

- Open a cmd window and invoke `C:\Users\myname\mycurl\curl.exe --help|more` to read screen by screen - or
- `C:\Users\myname\mycurl\curl.exe --help|clip` to copy the help to the clipboard and then paste to your preferred editor.
- Read the [curl manual online](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)