# Multiple commands cmd in a single line of for /f

Tags: cmd

I have run this command each line in cmd and works fine. How to run this command in cmd in one line?

I have try use `&` but i get different result if i run command line by line and use `&`.

```
for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do set str=%i
set string=%str:-=%
REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<%string%\>"
```

Below I attach a printscreen

[Command run line by line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMu3B.jpg)

[Command run with `&`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr16y.jpg)

Comment: You can simply create a batch file and run it once.

Comment: I have Kace K1000 and i want to insert this command in one line command.

Comment: @rubystallion It's more than that but you're right in suspecting a dup. This must have been asked before. But I'm too lazy to google the right one. :p

Comment: Just for the record, I don't see this as a duplicate of the post it was linked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

```
for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i& set string=!str:-=!& REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr \^<!string!\^>)
```

Note the parentheses around the compound statement, and the caret to escape the `<` `>` redirection. And if you need to enable delayed variable substitution in your cmd, use this:

```
cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i& set string=!str:-=!& REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr \^<!string!\^>)"
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer  but this is not work.
for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=%str:-=% && REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<%string%\>")

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: I have try run for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<!string!\>") and cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<!string!\>")" in cmd but not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help but your answer still not solve my problem

Comment: No problem. If you run the last one (with cmd /v:on...) in your cmd what do you get? And what operating system are you on?

Comment: If i run with cmd /v:on... i get The system cannot find the file specified. I use Windows XP sp 3.

Comment: What do you see when you run `cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && echo str=!str!)"` ? Please provide all output. Normally I'd see the for loop echo its substituted command before executing it. I'll switch to XP in a minute.

Comment: If i run cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && echo str=!str!)" i get result

(set str=00-AA-22-BB-33-CC   && echo str=!str! )

str=00-AA-22-BB-33-CC

Comment: Sorry i cannot attach printscreen.

Comment: It's ok, I got it. At least the for loop is working correctly. Next step would be to check this: `cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && echo string=!string!)"`

Comment: If i run cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && echo string=!string!)" i get result 
(set str=00-AA-22-BB-33-CC   && set string=!str:-=!   && echo string=!string! )
string=00AA22BB33CC

Comment: Then what do you get with `REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<00AA22BB33CC\>")` ?

Comment: If i run REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<00AA22BB33CC\>" without ")" at the end of command i get result NetworkAddress      REG_SZ  00AA22BB33CC. This result exactly as I expected.

Comment: Ok. But then I don't understand why the composed command failed. And what do you get with `cmd /v:on /c "REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-1‌​1CE-BFC1-08002bE1031‌​8} /s | findstr "\<00AA22BB33CC\>""` ?

Comment: If i run cmd /v:on /c REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\<00AA22BB33CC\>" without "" at the beginning and end of command i get result NetworkAddress REG_SZ 00AA22BB33CC. This result exactly as I expected.

Comment: I just learned that you need to escape the redirection symbols with a caret like so `^<` `^>`. Could you run that command: `cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\^<!string!\^>")"` ? I admit the whole command string is looking a bit like a hack now. :p

Comment: If i run cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s | findstr "\^<!string!\^>")" and export output to text file i get text file contains 1213 lines of sentences. I think this command show all registry in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}

Comment: And if you run this: `cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && echo "\^<!string!\^>")"`, what do you get? I'm trying to work towards your problem here on XP.

Comment: If i run cmd /v:on /c "for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do (set str=%i && set string=!str:-=! && echo "\^<!string!\^>")" i get result (set str=00-AA-22-BB-33-CC   && set string=!str:-=!   && echo "\<!string!\>" )
"\<00AA22BB33CC  \>"

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please test that cmd /v:on ... command and let me know.

Comment: Work perfect like magic. Thank you very much

Comment: I have been looking at this since 7 am here and really appreciate your feedback. Since I'm also preferred user of XP SP3 I just wanted to get this sorted out. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` character to separate lines, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd).

Comment: It is not work if i use &

Comment: It doesn't work in Kace K1000? It works in cmd for me. What error message do you get?

Comment: If i run command in cmd line by line work fine but if i use & this is not give result like run command line by line.

Comment: What result does it give then and how is it different?

Comment: If i run in cmd line by line i get result NetworkAddress      REG_SZ  00AA22BB33CC. If i use & i get result set str=00-AA-22-BB-33-CC   & set string=%str:-=%   & REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} /s   | findstr "\<%string%\>"

Comment: You also need to take care of delayed variable expansion. Use `!str:-=!` and `!string!`. I edited my answer, see there for a sample.