# Multiple commands in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

This command: `"start": "node server/server.js"` starts my server, but before running this I also want a command to run automatically:
`'webpack'`.

I want to build a script that can be run with
`npm run someCommand` - it should first run `webpack` in the terminal, followed by `node server/server.js`.

(I know how configure this with gulp, but I don't want to use it)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want firstly run webpack and after compile run nodejs. Maybe try this:

```
"start": "webpack && node server/server.js"
```

Comment: And how to pass args to both inner commands? For example I want to run "npm run start -- --dest dest/env" and I want dest arg for webpack and node command.

Answer (score 47):

The following *should* work:

`"start": "webpack && node server/server.js"`

Though, for readability (and especially if you plan on adding additional tasks in the future), you may want to consider creating separate entries for each task and then calling each of those from `start`. So, something like:

```
{
    "init-assets": "webpack",
    "init-server": "node server/server.js",
    "start": "npm run init-assets && npm run init-server"
}
```

Answer (score 27):

### Better understand the `&&` operator

In my case the **`&&` didn't work well** because one of my commands sometimes exited with non zero exit code (error) and the **`&&`** chaining operator **works only if the previous command succeeds**.

The main chaining operators behave like this:

- `&&` runs the next command only if the first **succeeds** (AND)
- `||` runs the next command only if the first **fails** (OR)

So if you want the second command **to run whatever the first has outputted** the best way is to do something like `(command1 && command2) || command 2`

### Others OS specific chaining operators

Other separators are different in a Unix (linux, macos) and windows environnement

- `;` UNIX run the second command whatever the first has outputted
- `;` WIN  separate command arguments
- `&` UNIX run first command in the background parallel to the second one
- `&` WIN  run the second command whatever the first has outputted

All chaining operators for windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430/5309984)
and for unix [here](https://www.tecmint.com/chaining-operators-in-linux-with-practical-examples/4)

Answer (score 15):

You can also chain commands like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force",
    "clean:complete": "npm run clean && npm uninstall -g @angular/cli && rmdir /Q /S node_modules",
    "clean:complete:install": "npm run clean:complete && npm i -g @angular/cli && npm i && npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"
}
```

Comment: How do I call it? npm run clean ? It will run all
Or I need to write npm run clean -complete -install ?

Comment: yes. npm run clean / npm run clean:complete. It's just a way to attach simultaneous commands.

Answer (score 9):

Also, along with the accepted answer and @pdoherty926's answer, in case you want to have run two command prompts, you can add "start" before each command:

```json
{
    "init-assets": "webpack",
    "init-server": "node server/server.js",
    "start": "start npm run init-assets && start npm run init-server"
}
```