# Launch a script from Python

Tags: python, cmd

I have the code that you can see below. I'm trying to go first to the directory and then,with the pipe "|" make a backup  of the MongoDB´s database.The problem is that when I launch the script the console returns me

> mongodump is not an internal or external command.

On the other hand,if I launch the same line

```
cd C:\\...\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.6\\bin | mongodump -h ip -d database name -o C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\BackUpMongo
```

in my system cmd it works without problems. Any idea?

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':

try:

    os.system('cd C:\\...\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.6\\bin | mongodump -h ip -d database name -o C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\BackUpMongo')


    print("Copia de seguridad finalizada")

except:
    print("Error during data base backup")


sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `&` or `&&` instead of `|`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.chdir()` instead of `os.system('cd ...')`.

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\\...\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.6\\bin')
os.system('mongodump -h ip -d database name -o C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\BackUpMongo')

print("Copia de seguridad finalizada")
```