# PHP exec() multiple commands that are not separate to each other

Tags: php, cmd, exec

Notes:

I have looked at other answers and they say to simply separate the answer with a  comma, but this doesn't work at all.

Scenario:

```
echo shell_exec('cd input');
echo shell_exec('dir'); //Checking the directory
echo shell_exec('program.exe'); //This is in the directory
echo shell_exec('dir'); //Checking the directory
```

What happens here  is that the commands  are of course  treated separately, so by the last "dir" the directory is still the same, and program.exe is never executed.

My attempts:

```
echo shell_exec('cd input; program.exe; dir');
```

This does not work, and I assume this is something to do with me on windows?

Comment: In windows they use `&` and `&&`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Thanks!