# Is there a way to automatically show the contents of a directory after a cd change in the windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, command-prompt, cd

So i want to change directory and view the new directory contents automatically with out having to type `cd folder` and then `dir` on the next line. Is there a way to adjust the settings on the windows cmd prompt such that every time you change directory it lists the contents automatically?

Comment: You can do two commands in one line like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes & No.
What you can do, is make `cd` and alias for `cd & dir`:

```
doskey cd=cd $* ^& dir
```

Note that these aliase are by standard only avaible for the session you define them. To use this alias persistent take a look at the tutorials I linked at the bottom.

**Explanation:**

`doskey` - create an alias/makro using `doskey.exe`

`cd $*` - Use `cd` with the argument given to the alias

`^&` - This uses the normal `&` for two commands with the `^` to as escape character

`dir` -make an `dir` in the directory you just moved in

---

Additional info about `doskey` can be found here:

[How to set an alias in Windows Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line)

[Setup Persistent Aliases & Macros in Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) using DOSKey](https://gist.github.com/vladikoff/38307908088d58af206b)

---

Additional warning (Thanks to @eryksun):

Note that `doskey.exe` is a command-line interface to the console's input alias and history facilities.

Console aliases are implemented in the console itself (i.e `conhost.exe`). They're defined per executable name (e.g. `cmd.exe` or `python.exe`), match at the beginning of a line, and replace the text that's read by the process via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`.

This means you **cannot** pipe into an alias or use one in a batch script. For that you need a custom batch script.

Comment: Note that doskey.exe is a command-line interface to the console's input alias and history facilities. Console aliases are implemented in the console itself (i.e conhost.exe). They're defined per executable name (e.g. cmd.exe or python.exe), match at the beginning of a line, and replace the text that's read by the process via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`. This means you cannot pipe into an alias or use one in a batch script. For that you need a custom batch script.

Comment: @eryksun Thx for the add up. I will append this to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure, i have never done that before but i have seen that you are able to do multiple commands in one line, the way to do this differs slightly depending on operating systems and other factors.

If this is what you are meaning then it has been mentioned and answered previously here

[How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)