# How to build Jekyll project production with Windows command line

Tags: jekyll

I try to build my jekyll project on production mode using JEKYLL_ENV variable but it doesn't work.

Jekyll documentation specifies to set a `production` environment in the build command :

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

But on Windows, this type of syntax is not correct.
I used this following syntax, but it looks not working:

```
jekyll build JEKYLL_ENV=production
```

I also set 'manually' this environment variable but doesn't take effect :

```
setx JEKYLL_ENV production & jekyll build
```

and

```
set JEKYLL_ENV=production & jekyll build
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this as well with my Windows/Jekyll setup. My workaround is to have production and development config files and set the `environment` variable in each file.

```
// _config.yml
environment: production
...<other config settings>...

--------

// _config_dev.yml
environment: development
```

Your prod environment should run `jekyll build` which automatically uses `_config.yml`. Your dev environment should run `jekyll <command> --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`. In the [Jekyll config docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options), "Settings in later [config] files override settings in earlier files." So, you can set the variable in prod and dev config files and use `--config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml` to set the variable in dev.

To do stuff with it in Jekyll, use Liquid statements to check for the environment variable. [Config files set](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#global-variables) `site` variables, so check `site.environment`

```
// some file that will be processed by Jekyll
{% if site.environment == "production" %}
    <do prod stuff>
{% elsif site.environment == "development" %}
    <do dev stuff>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

On windows you should run two commands:

the first command set env to production

```
set JEKYLL_ENV=production
```

the second command run `jekyll build` or `jekyll server`

```
jekyll build
```

when you use development evn, run this command again:

```
 set JEKYLL_ENV=development
```

Comment: This worked for me. What I do is I use `set JEKYLL_ENV=production` right before I run `jekyll build`. After it builds for production, I turn it back to dev with `set JEKYLL_ENV=development`.

Comment: This is what I needed! So used to working on Mac, key here is defining that `set` at the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
set JEKYLL_ENV=production | jekyll build
```

Running the two commands separately like Thxopen suggested worked. Then I tried running the two commands on one line using the separator character as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd), and it worked nicely.

Comment: the pipe didn't work but an & did. Win 10, command window.