# Unable to set Jekyll Environment to production on Windows 10

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme, azure-static-web-app

I've been trying for the past hour to build my jekyll site locally with JEKYLL_ENV=production with no success.
I've tried the following methods which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009824/how-to-build-jekyll-project-production-with-windows-command-line).

1. `set JEKYLL_ENV=production | jekyll build`
2. run one command at a time
   a. `set JEKYLL_ENV=production`
   b. `jekyll build`
3. edit `_config.yml` and add a line `environment: production`
4. Manually add a new `JEKYLL_ENV` environment variable with value `production` on my Windows 11

What am I missing? Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot?

My new site is based off the [Chirpy theme](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy), created using the [Chirpy Starter](https://github.com/cotes2020/chirpy-starter/generate)

I also noticed that my deployed site is also in development mode. I'm using the GitHub Actions automatically generated by Azure Static Web Apps using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-jekyll). This is even when I added the line `environment: production` to `_config.yml`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `jekyll JEKYLL_ENV=production build`?

Comment: @juicy-g just tried, and got this error `fatal: 'jekyll JEKYLL_ENV=production' could not be found. You may need to install the jekyll-JEKYLL_ENV=production gem or a related gem to be able to use this subcommand. `

Comment: Ok my comment above is not correct. It should be `jekyll build JEKYLL_ENV=production`. Are you using WSL or just plain command prompt on Windows?

Comment: @juicy-g thanks for helping me troubleshoot. It's still not working. I tried adding some random HTML in my footer with `{% if jekyll.environment == 'production' %} {% endif %}` and it doesn't enter this branch. I'm using plain windows command prompt, hoping I don't need WSL for this?