# Electron with Vue.js, not using a boilerplate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Not using a pre-existing boilerplate like [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue), I'd like to set up a Electron app with Vue.js. What is the procedure to do so, specifically for a *beginner*?

So far,I have installed vue cli globally with NPM, created my project with `vue create`, then installed electron into it with `npm install electron`.

From here is where everything falls apart. The [article I was following](https://medium.com/@mikeal/vue-js-electron-the-easy-way-adc3ca09234a) specifies starting the app with dev, which runs: `"NODE_ENV=DEV vue-cli-service serve & sleep 5 && NODE_ENV=DEV electron app.js"`. For whatever reason, this doesn't work. Comments on the article seem to suggest these commands are linux formatted, but no one has provided a windows formatted equivalent.

`electron .` starts the app, as expected, but vue components just dont work. Adding a basic `<script src=">` tag to the vue CDN at the top of the index.html works, and causes it to work, but ideally I'd like the electron app to work offline, which I believe was the point of using vue-cli as opposed to just importing it from the CDN.

Is there a simple way to do this? or would I be better off just downloading vue manually, throwing it into a folder in the electron app, and loading it with a script tag?

Comment: Not 100% sure what the Vue development server is, but looking closer I'm pretty sure its what I'm missing. Starting it manually with `npm serve` starts... something, but does not appear to make vue available to my electron page either.

Comment: "ideally I'd like the electron app to work offline, which I believe was the point of using vue-cli." I think you've misunderstood what vue-cli is; it's nothing to do with helping your app work offline, it just sets up webpack and all the other tooling for your development work.    electron-vue is one of several boilerplate setups that vue-cli can install for you (given your experience level I would *strongly* recommend using it instead of trying to set things up on your own.)

Comment: Clarified what I meant by that statement. I meant "Using Vue-CLI as opposed to importing from the CDN".

Comment: Ah, I see!  my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Windows Powershell if all PATH variables to `vue-cli-sevice` and `electron` are correct:

`set NODE_ENV=DEV ; vue serve ; timeout 5 ; electron app.js`

Note that the new version of vue changed some commands:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Windows command help:

[Setting and getting Windows environment variables from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt)

[How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

---

What solved the issue in the end was changing relative paths to absolute.

Also this was useful: https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/

Comment: It appears `&&` doesnt work at all in windows powershell, resulting in `The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.`, however, after replacing the `&&` with `;` as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4egx8v/not_working/), it boils down to a `the term 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized` error. Replacing it with npm run serve just causes the dev server to launch, and nothing after npm serve ever runs.

Comment: Does the updated version works? I also had that 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized error. That's why I linked the new vue installation website.

Comment: I'm now able to get a development server running consistently, but it doesn't start electron. it just takes up the whole prompt with https://pastebin.com/j0WNscHb. Meanwhile, NPM start still starts electron successfully. Nothing has yet gotten BOTH electron and vue started at the same time, however.

Comment: Okay, now I'm able to get rid of that error entirely, and even see my site on localhost when I have the dev server up and running. Still absolutely nothing in electron itself, however.

Comment: Have you tried to use one prompt window for each one of them? Does it work?

Comment: One prompt window each didnt work, until I changed the relative paths to absolute. Then it worked fine, so this is solved. Although, ultimately, as pointed out elsewhere this process is too finicky to be practical. While I didnt end up using a boilerplate, I ended up using electron-builder. https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/

Answer (score 2):

The **easiest** way to create an Electron app with vue.js as the frontend framework:

1. install vue-cli 3：

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

2. create a project (be patient because it may take a while):

`vue create myproject`

`cd myproject`

3. add and invoke the generator of vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder (it will automatically set up electron for you and let you check changed files):

`vue add electron-builder`

4. test your app:

`npm run electron:serve`

or build your app:

`npm run electron:build`

See more in this guide: https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/#to-start-a-development-server

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your answer, but isn’t the point of the question of how to setup `Vue.js` with `Electron` without a boilerplate?