# How to run multiple js servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, npm, nodemon

I'm developing a discord bot for discord at the moment, and to run the bot, I have a few different files. I've run into some problems along the way that all ended up having the same fix, or at least the only fix that I could come up with. That fix would be, instead of running them in my main file (index.js), I could just run 3 separate batch files using nodemon (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). I currently have 3 batch files to do so. Those batch files look like this:

```
nodemon index.js
pause
```

This would be for the main file.

```
nodemon logs.js
pause
```

This would be for the file that logs messages.

```
nodemon welcome and goodbye.js
pause
```

And this would be for the welcome and goodbye logs.

The only issue is, is that it clutters up my desktop with 3 different prompts, making it confusing as to what does what. I was wondering if it'd be possible with nodemon (or any other npm like this) for me to run all 3 of those batch files in one single command prompt.

And of course I'm open to other npms, but if I'd have to use another one, please include a way for it to automatically restart the server when I save the file in it as well (if possible). Since that's the main reason I like nodemon. I'd also like to be able to use a command prompt/batch file rather than the Visual Studio Code terminal.

If you're wondering what I mean when I say, "...automatically restart the server when I save the file," [image: I mean this]. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMk4y.jpg if it doesn't show, don't know how to format this stuff)
Whenever I save my code in Visual Studio it will restart and load the new code.

I'm still a little new to coding and stuff like that, so if my terminology is off I do apologize. If I did use a term incorrectly and you are confused/have a question about it, leave a comment and I will do my best too explain what I mean.

Thank you for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) or [parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel) in order to make it cross platform

example with concurrently:

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon index.js",
    "logs": "nodemon logs.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm:serve\" \"npm:logs\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
  }
}
```

**Edit:** you may want to take a look at the [VSCode Compound tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks)

[Here's an example setup](https://github.com/Teneff/so-concurrently)

Comment: In here? https://imgur.com/a/c28N7ZS If so where would I put it? Under or in ```"concurrently": "^5.0.0"``` Also how would I go about running it? Sorry don't quite understand all this.

Comment: @PeppaPapa just run `npm i -D concurrently` or `yarn add --dev concurrently`

Comment: I have it installed, but where do I put the script and how would I run with a batch file?

Comment: I put the code in and I get two errors: https://imgur.com/a/1fvMOCT

Comment: @PeppaPapa check the example I've just created

Comment: I did, thank you. Could you tell me how to start it though? If not that's fine. Thank you for the response and for putting up with stupid questions.

Comment: `npm install` to install the dependencies and `npm start` to run the start script

Comment: @PeppaPapa and to use the launch.json go to the debug tab in the VSCode

Answer (score 4):

Welcome :-)

I think you mean bash file (`.sh`) instead of batch file. So, in the terminal, you can `&&` commands to chain them together.

For example, you could chain them together like this:

`nodemon ./appOne/index.js && nodemon ./appTwo/index.js && nodemon welcome and goodbye.js`

and they will all execute at one time. Additionally, you could make a bash file somewhere on your computer that did exactly what I typed above :-)

Now if you wanted them to go to the background and you wanted to forget about them, you could put them in the background with one ampersand... like so:

`nodemon index.js &`

and it would disappear and you'd have your console back. It would also print out a process ID (PID) of what that node process is under, so you can find it and kill it later (via `kill -9 processid`)

Comment: ```nodemon ./appOne/index.js && nodemon ./appTwo/logs.js && nodemon welcome and goodbye.js```
So like this? Or would I change the ```./appOne``` stuff to be the whole directory or something else? And then would I save it as a .bat file? That is what I did with the others at first.

Comment: Oh my. You're on windows! .bat _is_ a batch file. Ahhh. Everything I wrote is probably wrong.

Comment: Gimme a hot second.

Comment: For windows, single ampersand will chain commands together regardless of the command's success/failure `&` https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055371/3622606

Comment: Generally, you can just keep making script files though -- .bat, .sh, whatever. Script files can execute other script files. If you're annoyed with how many commands you have to type, wrap it all up in a nice script file.

Comment: Okay well the first one you sent did work so thank you. And I don't mind it being there since I still use the rs command sometimes. It just got confusing with which window was which. Thanks a bunch for the quick replies, especially with how late it is. :)