# Error: Cannot find module while trying to run with nodemon

Tags: javascript, server, nodemon

I am trying to start two servers using `nodemon`.

```sh
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js && node serverpage.js"
  },
```

I installed `nodemon` correctly and when I try to execute it I get the following error:

```sh
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\puppe\Desktop\alles\Login-Projekt\login.js'
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Now the thing is that I can start both servers independently with no problems but they're failing to start together. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898386/how-to-run-multiple-js-servers

Comment: Yes I tried,but it didnt work tho.

Comment: Did you try using Concurrently, that can be an alternative to your problem, Seems like you login.js file is missing