# Is double ampersand (&&) really necessary for windows batch scripts, shortcuts and other non-live cmd methods?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

This question is based off @ZaLiTHkA's reply of the accepted answer of the running cmd commands sequentially question seen below.

> Just for the sake of clarity: you should note the single `&` symbol here is explicitly for a live command prompt. When commands are run by passing a string to be executed as a script (shortcuts, batch files, etc.. ), then double `&&` are required – [ZaLiTHkA Apr 3 '14 at 20:28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd/8055390#comment34854597_8055390)

Is `&&` really necessary for running script commands (i.e. shortcuts or batch files)? I've found I am still able to run a simple command like: `cmd /k echo foo & echo bar` in the run window and execute a shortcut of the same target/command, without a problem. Would appreciate any clarification or documentation explicitly saying *why* and *if* `&&` is actually the recommended method for batch scripts since it seems a single `&` seems to work as well.

Note: This is a not a question distinguishing the difference between `&&` and `&` definitions, but why && is required as pointed out by @ZaLiTHkA's very visibly upvoted comment.

Comment: My advice is to always ignore points/votes, just because something has been voted for by people doesn't make it correct, which in this case is true.

Comment: ss64 is very useful, see [How-to: Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just for the sake of clarity: you should note the single & symbol here
>   is explicitly for a live command prompt. When commands are run by
>   passing a string to be executed as a script (shortcuts, batch files,
>   etc.. ), then double && are required. – [ZaLiTHkA Apr 3 '14 at 20:28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd/8055390#)

**The comment is nonsense!**

As the answer already explained, there is a semantical difference between `&` and `&&`.

It only depends on the intention, which one should be used.

In the case of `echo a & echo b`, there is no good reason to ever use `&&` instead, because the second `echo` shall be executed, independent of the first `echo`.

In the case of `cd C:\myDir\ && del *.*` it's wise to use `&&` to prevent unwanted deletion somewhere, when the `cd` fails.

[I comment on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd/8055390#comment106739772_8055390), too.

Comment: In other words, when using commandX && commandY the commandY is only executed if commandX succeeds;