# `package.json` sequential start script only execute one of the script

Tags: node.js, webpack, package.json, nodemon

I have the following `scripts` property in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack -w && nodemon server.js",
    "watch:server": "nodemon server.js",
    "watch:build": "webpack -w",
},
```

When I run `npm run start` it only starts the `webpack -w` command but not the `nodemon server.js` command. I thought having `&&` will run the scripts sequentially but it is definitely not the case for me. I have seen many people chaining execution with `&&` and it works fine.

Why is mine not working?

Answer (score 0):

If `webpack -w` is not finishing successfully, your second command `nodemon server.js` won't run. Using a single `&` should allow the second one to run even if the first one fails.

Comment: But I want to run `nodemon` after `webpack` hence the `&&`. And I am pretty sure that `webpack` finished successfully.. Its just that `nodemon` won't run after it.

Comment: Not sure why `&&` would not work unless `webpack` is exiting with an error. If you don't care whether or not it succesfully exits my answer should work fine. Please see this answer if you want more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/14104186