# how to delete a directory in cmd, without deleting its content?

Tags: cmd, del, rmdir

Im new to cmd, and I was given a task to delete a directory, without deleting its content, in one line.
How can I do that?
I had already tried `rmdir` and `del`, but they remove the content of the directory along with it.
I thought about using `move` first in order to move the content, but I have no idea as for how to do it along with deleting the folder in one line.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why one line? You can't delete the directory without moving the files and I can't think of a tool that handles it as a single command.

Comment: that was the task i was given, i don't know why. im just trying to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like this on all Microsoft OSes since 2000, and still good today:
>
> ```
> dir & echo foo
> ```
>
> If you want the second command to execute only if the first exited successfully:
>
> ```
> dir && echo foo
> ```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/9872288).

So you can easily move, then delete the folder all in one line.

Comment: If this solves your question please mark as solved for future users reference :)

Comment: @Erel, please do not mark this answer as the solution to your question, because it is not. This shows you two methods of combining one or more commands as a single line, it does not move contents or delete/remove objects. It is therefore an incomplete answer, technically it assists you with only a portion of what your question asks. If you only wanted to know how to combine multiple commands onto a single line, then you should upvote the linked answer, and delete your question, or edit your question accordingl, and it will be closed as a duplicate of that linked above.