# Compile and run at the same time with a single line command in windows

Tags: c++, c

In macOS whenever I compile and execute my code I use
g++ name.cpp && ./a.out

but in Windows it doesn't work for compile and run i use

```
g++ name.cpp
./a.exe
```

I'm using command prompt.
g++ name.cpp && ./a.exe doesn't work.
But i want to use a single line command like i used to do in macOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: Specify whether you are using `cmd` or Powershell. Specify how "it doesn't work"; what error do you get??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, backslash (or yen mark on some font) is used as separator of directory.

```
g++ name.cpp && .\a.exe
```

worked on Command Prompt (but not on PowerShell).

Comment: && doesn't work (& not allowed)

Comment: @SanskarJaiswal This [works for me](https://i.imgur.com/MFlSaVx.png).

Comment: I didn't even noticed that i was using powershell i thought i was using cmd . Then i changed it to cmd in vs-code ...Thank You so much

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the two different commands using &&.
2. For invoking the application it depends on your terminal:
   a - you have to use '\' not '/' when using powershell: (.\a.exe)
   b - just call the executable when using the ancient dos terminal: (a.exe)