# Split long command line in DosBox

Tags: batch-file, command-line, split, dos, dosbox

I have a batch file I need to run in DOSBOX to run 16-bit program. It was originally written for MS-DOS with long command line with "&" to split command lines.

for example:

```
MyCommand aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, dddd, eeeee &
fffff, ggggg, hhhhh &
iiiii, jjjjj, kkkkk
```

The "&" doesn't work in DOSBOX.

I know that "^" works for Windows Command Prompt, but it doesn't work for DOSBOX.

So, how do I do it in DOSBOX, splitting long command line to several lines in a batch file.

Thanks,
Oren.

Comment: Why not just do two separate commands, one before the `&` and one after it? imo there's only one reason to ever chain commands with an ampersand, and it isn't applicable here.

Comment: This might be better asked in [retrocomputing.se], as MS-DOS is no longer supported. Be aware that DOSBOX identifies as MS-DOS 5, so if the capability you are inquiring about didn't appear until MS-DOS 6, it may not be implemented at all in DOSBOX.

Comment: Alternatively, search or ask on the [DOSBox Forum](https://www.vogons.org/viewforum.php?f=53)

Comment: @SomethingDark [DOS is severely crippled](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386) and doesn't support that syntax

Comment: @Oren [Try `Ctrl+T` to see if it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/995714)

Comment: @phuclv - DOS doesn't support running one command and then running a second command? Because that's what my recommendation was to do.

Comment: @SomethingDark yes, command.com doesn't have that capability. Ctrl+T works in MS-DOS 6 but DOSBOX is MS-DOS 5

Comment: @phuclv - You understand that I'm saying to enter a command, press enter, and then enter the second command and press enter, right? Like instead of `cls&echo hi` you'd type `cls`, press enter, type `echo hi` and press enter again.

Comment: @SomethingDark sometimes you don't have that choice, for example `command /c "cls & echo hi"`

Comment: True, at that point you'd just have to create a script and run that. Unfortunately, the actual command in question here hasn't been revealed so it's hard to give useful advice.

Comment: What version of MS-DOS could use & like you claim? I have never seen it done in MS-DOS.