# How to keep cmd running after opening a .bat file script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

Basically I have written a "script" in notepad and saved it as a `.bat` file. All it does is to change directory. Written like this:

```
cd C:\Users\Hello\Documents\Stuff
```

It does change the directory, but i want to write more after that, within the `cmd`. Ex. choose a program to run. It seems simple, but i can't figure it out. I read about `pause`, but it just waits for a key and then closes down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent auto-closing of console after the execution of batch file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Put `cmd /k` on the very last line of the script.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
Cmd /k
```

`cmd /k` starts a new `cmd` instance, `/k` stops terminating the console window after the commands are finished.

Answer (score 3):

end your bat file with `@pause` on its own line

Comment: @pause seems to do the same as just pause. It wont let me write, it closes no matter what i press.

Comment: ahh, your after the script changing directory for you and then you doing more stuff manually yourself? "cmd C:\Users\Hello\Documents\Stuff". the bat file runs as if it is its own app, you need to tell it to launch a new instance of cmd

Comment: Once i get it to launch a new cmd, can i then get it to close the old? So i only have one open. Or maybe just run the old hidden? I know you can hide text with "@echo off", perhaps also for the whole cmd?

Comment: thanks @Endoro. Googling for 10 minutes and "very last line of the script" is the key here.