# Keep CMD open after BAT file executes

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file like this:

```
ipconfig
```

That will print out the IP info to the screen, but before the user can read that info CMD closes itself.

I believe that CMD assumes the script has finished, so it closes.

How do I keep CMD open after the script is finished?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/stop-a-batch-file-from-autoclosing

Comment: @RobKielty it's the same question alright - but here we have a new answer (which is better IMHO)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep cmd running after opening a .bat file script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012344/how-to-keep-cmd-running-after-opening-a-bat-file-script)

Comment: @alfasin Is that not the same as Rutger Nijlunsing's answer?

Comment: @RobKielty nope, my answer isn't the same as it doesn't use `pause` which is a nice workaround (and that's why I upvoted this answer) but not one that really solves the issue because after the user hits `Enter` or `Space` the window will close...

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Depending on how you are running the command, you can put `/k` after `cmd` to keep the window open.

```
cmd /k my_script.bat
```

Simply adding `cmd /k` to the end of your batch file will work too. Credit to [Luigi D'Amico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4141943/luigi-damico) who posted about this in the comments below.

Comment: After all your scripts in your bat file - put --> cmd /k

Comment: Beware that if your program contains syntactical errors, the window will still close if you ran it via double-click and put `cmd /k` at the end.

Comment: This doesn't explain cmd windows closing if the user double clicked the file.

Comment: This command seems to reset my shell. If use it in a 'Git Bash' shell (a modified cmd prompt that came with my git installation) on windows, the the command prompt is reverted to the standard version and won't remember the the commands I typed in... Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 342):

Put `pause` at the end of your .BAT file.

Comment: If you still want to interact with the bat file after your execution, replace the PAUSE with just cmd /k - then after your scripts have run, you can still run manual commands afterwards in the same context

Comment: If the last command fails pause won't work. As a workaround one can use `call` before the last command to ensure pause works.

Answer (score 76):

Just add **`@pause`** at the end.

Example:

```
@echo off
ipconfig
@pause
```

Or you can also use:

```
cmd /k ipconfig
```

Comment: what does the @ symbol do? Is there a difference between @pause and pause?

Comment: @demonicdaron Answer explaining the @ symbol: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21077142/2258

Comment: But in this case, it should not make any difference.

Comment: The difference between **`@pause`** and **`pause`** can be seen visually in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957076#60053224

Comment: Here, it does not make any difference as "echo" is already set to "off".

Answer (score 30):

When the .bat file is started **not from within the command line** (e.g. double-clicking).

```
echo The echoed text
@pause
```

[image: at_pause]

```
echo The echoed text
pause
```

[image: pause]

```
echo The echoed text
cmd /k
```

[image: cmd k]

```
echo The echoed text & pause
```

[image: and_pause]

Answer (score 12):

Adding `pause` in (Windows 7) to the end did not work for me
but adding the `cmd /k` in front of my command did work.

Example :

```
cmd /k gradlew cleanEclipse
```

Answer (score 6):

`start cmd /k` did the magic for me. I actually used it for preparing cordova phonegap app it runs the command, shows the result and waits for the user to close it. Below is the simple example

```
start cmd /k echo Hello, World!
```

What I did use in my case

```
start cmd /k cordova prepare
```

**Update**

You could even have a title for this by using

`start "My Title" echo Hello, World!`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows add '& Pause' to the end of your command in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the script within the command line, then add `exit /b` to keep CMD opened

Comment: Doesn't practically solve the question as modifying `ipconfig` and other built-in batch files ***is a very bad idea***.

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused as to why we're adding a `cmd` at the beginning and I was wondering if I had to open the command prompt first.
What you need to do is type the full command along with `cmd /k`. For example assume your batch file name is "my_command.bat" which runs the command `javac my_code.java` then the code in your batch file should be:

```
cmd /k javac my_code.java
```

So basically there is no need to open command prompt at the current folder and type the above command but you can save this code directly in your batch file and execute it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Putting "call" in front of my last command followed by a "cmd /k" command worked for me.

```
call mvn clean package
cmd /k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -d C:\xxx\lib\ -classpath C:\xxx\lib\ *.java

cmd cd C:\xxx\yourbat.bat
```

the second command make your cmd window not be closed.
The important thing is you still able to input new command

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote this also works when running a command directly from the search bar in windows.

e.g. directly running `ipconfig` will directly close the cmd window after the command has exited.

[image]

Using `cmd \k <command>` won't - which was what i was trying to do when i found this answer.

[image]

It has the added advantage of always recognizing the command you're trying to run. E.g. running `echo hello world` from the searchbar won't work because that is not a command, however `cmd \k echo hello world` works just fine.