# Gain manual control of cmd after batch file execution

Tags: batch-file

I am putting conditional statement for exit in batch file.

```
:choice
set /P c=Do you want to exit [y/n]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :optA
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :optB
goto :choice

:optA

pause 
exit

:optB
pause >nul
```

pause>nul does not work as expected.

I wish to have gain control in command prompt once I say No in the exit options in above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep CMD open after BAT file executes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957076/keep-cmd-open-after-bat-file-executes) & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/stop-a-batch-file-from-autoclosing

Comment: @B.K. I had checked this but that didn't solve my concern.

Comment: Alright, then what is the problem?  You're not telling us how it doesn't work for you.  "...does not work as expected" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: it throws the same prompt 'Do you want to quit[y/n]' and irrespective of options typed in, it just closes the prompt. I am trying to regain control of command prompt once I type in 'N/n' in the Do you want to quit option.

Comment: Check the update in my answer.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:optB
cmd /k
```

Another option is to simply do it as:

```
:optB
cmd.exe
```

This will start the `cmd` instance within the same window, after the execution of batch file is done, if option B is chosen.

You can also just do it as:

```
:optB
cmd
```

...without the extension.

Comment: pause> nul Doesn't help

Comment: @user007 I didn't tell you to use `paus> nul`.  I told you to try `pause`.

Comment: Pause doesn't help either.

Comment: It works but it shows the below message, can we do something to bypass this message so that it looks seamless?

`Do you want to exit [y/n]?n
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

Comment: @user007 Try the `cmd /k` version.  It's the top one.

Comment: cmd /k worked, thank you so much. Thats what I was looking for.

Comment: @user007 Glad we were able to figure it out.