# VBA: Shell() command to keep CMD after execution completes

Tags: excel, vba

I am executing a **.py** python script from VBA using the **Shell()**

```
Sub Run_Python()
    
    Dim PYTHON_FULL_PATH, PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH As String   
    iRowNo = 2
    Do Until Sheet7.Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        PYTHON_FULL_PATH = Sheet7.Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH = Sheet7.Cells(iRowNo, 2)
    
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop
    
    RetVal = Shell(PYTHON_FULL_PATH & " " & PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH, vbNormalFocus)
    

End Sub
```

The Python script prints few lines as part of the code and those print statements are shown in the  CMD prompt.

But once the execution completes or errored our the CMD gets closed automatically.

Is there a way to keep the CMD prompt visible even after the execution gets completed ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried the same commands you’d normally use in a command prompt? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966906/2727437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run cmd.exe with [/k parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd):

```
RetVal = Shell("cmd /k " & PYTHON_FULL_PATH & " " & PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH, vbNormalFocus)
```