# How to enable user actions after .bat file is executed

Tags: batch-file, cmd

First thing first, i don't write cmd programs usually, so that's why i'm asking for this very basic question.

My problem is:
I have a .bat file that list some actions, all of them works fine, except for one.
This is the code, so that it will be easier to explain:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
cd C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools
adb devices
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ************************************
ECHO Select what to do next:
ECHO ************************************
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Check devices status
ECHO 2 - Disable auto update for this device
ECHO 3 - Enable auto update for this device
ECHO 4 - Install app.apk
ECHO 5 - Other actions
ECHO 6 - Close
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO CHECKDEV
IF %M%==2 GOTO DISABLEUPD
IF %M%==3 GOTO ENABLEUPD
IF %M%==4 GOTO INSTALLAPP
IF %M%==5 GOTO OTHER
IF %M%==6 GOTO EOF
:CHECKDEV
adb devices -l
GOTO MENU
:DISABLEUPD
adb pull /system/app/SystemUpdater.apk C:\Android\QuickCommands\autoUpdateBackup
adb remount
adb shell rm /system/app/SystemUpdater.apk 
GOTO MENU
:ENABLEUPD
ECHO. Currently it doesn't work. :(
GOTO MENU
:INSTALLAPP
adb install C:\src\heatgeniusapp\release\android\app.apk
GOTO MENU
:OTHER
set todir=C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools
```

What I want is that when you press 5 (GOTO OTHER), the cmd will be at this address:

```
C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools
```

And ready to write some custom command and execture them as normal..
how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
have a good day

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep cmd running after opening a .bat file script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012344/how-to-keep-cmd-running-after-opening-a-bat-file-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `cmd /k` on the very last line of the script. `CD yourpath` will "bring" your cmd to the desired directory. And use the search function next time ;-)

```
...
:OTHER
CD /D C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools
CMD /K
```

You can skip `/D` if you are sure that your bat file is on the same drive as the target folder (C:\Android\adk\sdk\platform-tools), means both are on C:
I would still keep `/D`

Comment: thank you! it worked fine and sorry if this one was a duplicate.