# How to run java program using a .bat file exactly?

Tags: java, batch-file

Using

```
@echo off
javac source.java
java source
```

I am able to create source.class file and also run but the out window is not persisting...
When `java` source executes the `cmd` just blinks and goes off but I want that window visible until we close it. Please help me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can run the .jar with `java -jar program.jar`

Comment: @Sbls: But there is no Jar here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/stop-a-batch-file-from-autoclosing

Answer (score 3):

use `PAUSE` at end of your batch file

Comment: yeah I tried with it but an applet program is not showing the applet, using pause it is displaying only text written in the program and not taking the input also