# How can I fix my frozen python program from cx freeze that opens cmd for a tenth of a second then closes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to find out why my exe opens a command for a tenth of a second and then closes. I have been using cx freeze for 3.4 python and I've added the directories to my path. I have been looking for a solution for about 48 hours now . I have also tried using a batch file to open it which just opens a plain command which is named the directory of my exe. the actual python file works fine. I have tried uninstalling cx freeze multiple times as well as have deleted my build file and tried to re build it with the command python setup.py build. I have also tried 
    python setup.py bdist_msi

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EOVY.png)

Comment: If you can use a batch file, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file

Comment: Sounds like you have an error with your changes.  Can you detail your OS and how you are using cx_freeze.  If you are trying to make a "compiled" exe to distribute have you tried PyInstaller?