# How to connect to adb using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, adb

I want to create a batch file which will open command prompt and connect to adb after changing the directory. My current code opens command prompt and change the directory but does not executes the last command of connecting to adb. If anyone can help me in this direction, it would be great.

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd.exe /K "cd C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"
adb connect 192.168.200.25:5555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmd /k starts a command prompt process that runs a command and does not quit afterwards. Why are you using cmd.exe at all?

```
@echo off
cd /d c:\users\sam\appdata\local\android\sdk\platform-tools\
adb connect 192.168.200.25:5555
```

Comment: It really works. But the command prompt closes after connecting to adb. Is there any command to keep it open even after connecting? @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file

Comment: Thanks so much. Adding `cmd /k` below did it. Now the console is not closing.