# Cmd keeps closing after running the .bat

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have made a program in eclipse that works fine with the code,

```
java -jar FoodVan.jar
```

in the command prompt however when I try to do it in a .bat file it just closes as soon as it has got to the end, how would I keep it open?
I know there is a few like this however it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "pause" without quotes to the last line of the .bat file. It pauses the display and keeps the window open.